# How to use the SSH Key that I configured in the github, for CLI git push on Windows?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am on Windows 11.

I created a SSH keypair using `ssh-keygen -o` and saved it in say `c:/work/ssh`, and I have copied the contents of `id_rsa.pub` into my github.com account -> *Settings* -> *Add new SSH Key*

Now, How do I make my windows Git CLI **use** the key when I do a git push ?

Also, my git push/pull etc. works with my company's git repositories, so I want to keep that working. Just that I need to use the new SSH-Key to connect to github.com repos and push stuff.

Comment: Note that Git-for-windows often comes with *its own* ssh, separate from the Windows ssh (because older Windows either lacks ssh entirely or has an inadequate one). Windows 11 ssh should be fine for Git to use, but you may need to configure your Git to use the Windows ssh implementation, by setting `core.sshCommand` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

ssh config file is apt for your situation. You create a simple text file named config and place it in .ssh folder under C:\Users<your windows id>.

In this file, you list different hosts and corresponding parameters.
Following are sample config file contents.

```
 host github.com
      HostName github.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa

 host git.mycompany.com
      HostName git.mycompany.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitprivate_rsa
```

Most of the time your user name may differ between the systems. You can use `User my_id` to set appropriate user id along with the above properties.
Refer `Configuring public key authentication` section at https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/config

Comment: How do I make git pickup this config ? If I place it under the .ssh folder, will git automatically pick it up?

Comment: Yes, Jerald, placing the config in .ssh folder should be good enough.